# using multiple characters as delimiters in Coldfusion list

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to use multiple characters as the delimeter in ColdFusion list like `,`( comma and blank) but it ignores the blank.

I then tried to use:

```
<cfset title = listappend( title, a[ idx ].title, "#Chr(44)##Chr(32)#" ) />
```

But it also ignores the blank and without blanks the list items to diffucult to read.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With ListAppend you can only use one delimiter. As the docs say for the delimiters parameter:

> If this parameter contains more than one character, ColdFusion uses only the first character.

I'm not sure what `a[ idx ].title` contains or exactly what the expected result is (would be better if you gave a complete example), but I think something like this will do what you want or at least get you started:

```
<cfscript>
a = [
    {"title"="One"},
    {"title"="Two"},
    {"title"="Three"}
];
result = "";

for (el in a) {
    result &= el.title & ", ";
}

writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a fundamental flaw in your approach here. The list delimiter is part of the *structure* of the data, whereas you are also trying to use it for "decoration" when you come to output the data from the list. Whilst often conveniently this'll work, it's kinda conflating two ideas.

What you *should* do is eschew the use of lists as a data structure completely, as they're a bit crap. Use an array for storing the data, and then deal with rendering it as a separate issue: write a render function which puts whatever separator you want in your display between each element.

```
function displayArrayAsList(array, separator){
    var list = "";
    for (var element in array){
        list &= (len(list) ? separator : "");
        list &= element;
    }
    return list;
}
writeOutput(displayAsList(["tahi", "rua", "toru", "wha"], ", "));
```

> tahi, rua, toru, wha

Answer (score 1):

Use a two step process.  Step 1 - create your comma delimited list.  Step 2

```
yourList = replace(yourList, ",", ", ", "all");
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't have access to creating the list in the first place. This works in that instance.